# Does $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\log(P_1(k))}{\log(k)}$ exist?

Tags: calculus, limits, number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Wikipedia gives the definition of the Golomb-Dickman constant as $$\lambda=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{\log(P_1(k))}{\log(k)}$$Where $P_1(x)$ is the largest prime factor of $x$.

My question is if $$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\log(P_1(k))}{\log(k)}$$converges or not, and if so to what number? The upper and lower bounds of $P_1(k)$ are $k$ and $2$ respectively. Taking the average of the two, we get $\frac{k+2}2$. Substituting this for $P_1(k)$, we get $1$. This is a heuristic argument, so I am not sure.

Edit: I am now suspecting that the limit in question doesn't exist because of the unpredictable nature of $P_1(k)$.

Comment: $\log(P_1(k)) / \log(k)$ does not converge to $1$. For the subsequence $k=2^j$, the terms approach zero.

Comment: The limit does not exist: the subsequence of powers of two gives a limit of zero whereas the subsequence of primes gives a limit of one.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Is this a known theorem? What is it called? Please make this an answer - it is short but it does the job.

Comment: @KamalSaleh It is trivial. If $k$ is a prime then $P_1(k)=k$. If $k$ is a power of two then $P_1(k) =2$.

Comment: @Gary I deleted this question long ago, and I undeleted. I forgot to undelete the answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

Credit to @TheSimpliFire:

The limit in question doesn't exist. This is because the limit is different for different subsequences (for example the primes and the powers of 2).